# Benefits of mod_pagespeed over mod_deflate

Tags: apache, mod-pagespeed, mod-deflate

The [SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883162/what-does-mod-pagespeed-do) explains what mod_pagespeed does, but I'm wondering if I would notice any significant difference in page load time with this installed on a server that is already using mod_deflate to compress files.

If it is worth installing, are there any special considerations to take into account with regards to configuration when running both modules, or should one replace the other? The server is running EasyApache4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will because these modules do different things.

`mod_deflate` handles data [compression](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html)

> The mod_deflate module provides the DEFLATE output filter that allows
>   output from your server to be compressed before being sent to the
>   client over the network.

Simply put, its sole purpose is to reduce the amount of bytes sent for your server regardless of what kind of data is sent

`mod_pagespeed` performs optimizations that would speed up the resulting webpage performance from *end user's perspective* by following a bunch of web pages optimization [best-practices](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rules)

Here's a simple example:

- imagine we have 1 html page and 1 small external javascript file
- if we use `mod_deflate`, both of them will be gzipped BUT the browser would need to make 2 HTTP requests to fetch them
- `mod_pagespeed` may decide it's worth inlining the contents of this js file into the .html page
- if we use `mod_deflate` together with `mod_pagespeed` in this case the resulting number of bytes downloaded would be the same BUT the page would render faster as it would need to make only 1 single HTTP request

Such optimizations of the original .html page and its dependent resources may have a huge difference in terms of execution time especially on slow mobile networks

So the idea is to always enable `mod_deflate` and either apply these best-practices manually or use `mod_pagespeed` which would apply them automatically

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. I already call deflate in .htaccess, and from reading on the web mod_pagespeed is run automatically once installed. So do they work ok together? Does mod_pagespeed run first then mod_deflate?

Comment: Yes they can be combined. You can examine your http headers to make sure gzip encoding is present and that would mean mod_deflate works fine